# How to sort one column via several ways in a header?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have the tablesorter from [motti](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) and I can't find out a simple way to sort a certain column in more than one way from 2 different hot areas in the same header. (One way via "gamename" and another via "percentage".)
My code already sorts on Game on the gamename, but it does do the same when clicking on percentage (so the latter not by percentage, but by name).

***What's the least-code way to do this?*** (Preferably with existing tablesorter options.)

**Table header column:**

```
<th>Game <span class="percSort">%</span></th>
```

**Body column:**

```
<th class="gamename">
<div style="width:66%;background-color: hsla(84,100%,50%,0.7);"></div>
<span class="name">Alphabetic</span>
<span class="perc">66%</span>
</th>
```

**Domready code:**

```
    $("#games")
    .tablesorter({
        sortList: [['.percSort',1]],
        textExtraction:{
            1:function(node, table, cellIndex) {
                return $(node).find('.name').text();
            },
            '.percSort':function(node, table, cellIndex) {
                return $(node).find('.perc').text();
            }
       }
    });
```

**What I cannot do:** split my corresponding column in more column. It displays colored bars via the css you can see.

Comment: How about setting up an event `$('.percSort').click(function(){ $("#games").trigger("sorton", [ [[0,0]] ]) });`?

Comment: `$("#games .percSort").on( "click", function(e) {
  $("#games").trigger("sorton", [ [[1,0]] ]);
 });`
That will trigger the gamename sorting, not the percentage sorting.
Also, is there really no built-in approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between the two sorting options are. The same column is sorted differently? Does the column contain two values or how is it sorted differently?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I described that well. Yes, the same column has 2 sorting options, or should have. In my code, you can see there are 2 values in the column, one class name and one class perc. I don't know how to make this more clear.

Comment: Right, give a few minutes to make something up - I'm pretty sure there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the text extraction works is that it is only used when the table is initialized or updated. It's not really meant to sort two different blocks of information within the same cell, but it would be possible to use it to format the text a certain way, then use the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textsorter) to sort the desired part ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3393/)):

```
$(function () {

    var $cell;
    $('#games').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            0: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
                var $n = $(node);
                // add semi-colon between values
                return $n.find('.name').text() + ';' + $n.find('.perc').text();
            }
        },
        textSorter: function (a, b) {
            var x = a.split(';'),
                y = b.split(';'),
                i = $cell && $cell.is('.active') ? 1 : 0;
            return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
        },
        initialized: function () {
            $cell = $('#games').find('.percSort');

            // trigger sort here because any initial sort using sortList
            // won't have the $cell variable defined, so it defaults to name
            $('#games').trigger('sorton', [ [[1,1]] ]);

            $cell.click(function () {
                // activate percentage sort
                $cell.addClass('active');
                return false;
            }).closest('th').click(function () {
                // clicking on header outside of percSort
                // inactivates the percentage sort
                $cell.removeClass('active');
            });

        }
    });

});
```

---

Updates:

- To make sure the column doesn't get detected to only use a percent parser, set the sorter type in the header:

  ```
  <th class="nameHead sorter-text">Game...</th>
  ```
- To make the table initially sort the percent, you need to do two things:

  - Add the "active" class to the cell `<span class="perc active">&nbsp;66%&nbsp;</span>`
  - Add `$('#games').trigger('sorton', [ [[1,1]] ]);` because the `$cell` variable isn't defined until after tablesorter has initialized. And you can't define it before because the headers are rebuilt during initialization. Code added to the example above.

Comment: This is the better answer. Nice having the developer around to troubleshoot. ;)

Comment: This shows you know your tablesorter, Mottie!  I'm honoured! I also hope I brought you guys something nice to think about, since it was kinda new for tablesorter, wasn't it? :-}

Comment: P.S. Any way to default sort on percentage (init and update) via tablesorter settings ?

Comment: `<span class="perc active">66%</span>`

Comment: Argh, for some reason it doesn't work for me. I've pasted all my code in fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/76GUL/2/) if any of you can see a quick mistake that is not obvious for me.. :(

Comment: See the console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: doAjPost is not defined`

Comment: Oops! Forgot about that. Don't think the fault is in the ajax, so I'll just remove it. It still doesn't work. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/76GUL/3/)

Comment: Ok, got it... you just need to change the sort type since it is setting it to sort percentages. Just add the `sorter-text` class: `<th class="nameHead sorter-text">Game...</th>`

Comment: Wow!  So fast!  Thanks a lot!!
P.S. You don't happen to also know how to remove the sorting on the second header row cells ? I searched in doc. without success so far.

Comment: Add `sorter-false` class name to those header cells

Comment: I tried that already from docs, but doesn't work.  
It DOES work if I put it on a th above for example, but than still the arrows appear and it just disables the sorting of the whole column; i just want the second row cells not to be another clickable header, but still allow sorting on that column via the header above.
(Your "active" class from you comment above also doesn't work :( Murhpy is against me today).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57022/discussion-between-mottie-and-r-u-bn).

Comment: Here is an update from @Mottie that covers 1. default ordering 2. second row headers disabled. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76GUL/27/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with an existing option as the tablesorter only allows you to set (and not change) a single sorting order for a column. There is however a workaround, which simply switches a custom parser off and on depending on where on the header you click:

**Table header column:**

```
<th id="thgame">Game <span class="percSort">%</span></th>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Add custom table parser for percentage.
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'perc',
  format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
    return $(cell).find('.perc').text().slice(0, -1);
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});

// Create tablesorter and disable default sorting for column.
$('#games').tablesorter({ ... });
$('#thgame').unbind();

// Create custom sorting events for column.
$('#thgame').click(function(){ 
    $('#thgame').removeClass('sorter-perc');
    $('#games').trigger('updateRows');
    $('#games').trigger('sorton', [ [[0,'n']] ]);
});
$('.percSort').click(function(e){ 
    $('#thgame').addClass('sorter-perc');
    $('#games').trigger('updateRows');
    $('#games').trigger('sorton', [ [[0,'n']] ]);
    e.stopPropagation() // prevent previous event from firing.
});
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer @Banana, but I couldn't get this to work without changing the `$('#extracolumn')` into `$('#thgame')` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3394/)). The difference between our solutions is that your would be slower for larger tables because you're refreshing the entire cache, otherwise it works pretty good :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I added your code/demo to the [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki) under "Sorting". Honestly, my answer is a bit more complex and might not be as straight-forward a method as yours. Either way works just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I'm honoured.

Comment: First of, you guys are great. Really examplary (open source) developers!
I like the answer of Mottie better though. (complete th area, update compatibiliy (i guess?), ..). Sorry, Banana, but I appreciate your help and trigger! (You agreed too, I see. :-) )

Comment: At least give him a +1! ;)

Comment: I did! What do you mean? Am I missing a place to do that?
[Edit] Hm..apparently it was taken away, I +1'd it again.  Weird. I put it back. Thanks for noticing. [Edit] It's a bug, if you click twice on the arrow above, it takes back your vote; should only happen on the arrow down in my opinion, but well..