# JQuery Tablesorter text extraction not working as intended

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Please find my HTML and javascript below. I am trying to sort a column in the table based on what radio button is selected.

```
<table id="test">
 <thead><tr><th>data</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td><span>1.00 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$5,000</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>0.50 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$300.00</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>1.40 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$0</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>1.20 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$500</span></td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


$("#test").tablesorter({
            textExtractionCustom: {
                0: function (node) {
                    if ($('#radio-choice-h-2a').is(':checked')) {
                        return $(node).find("span").first().text().replace('%', '').replace(' ', '');
                    }
                    else if ($('#radio-choice-h-2b').is(':checked')) {
                        return $(node).find("span").last().text().replace('$', '').replace(',', '');
                    }
                    else {
                        return $(node).find("span").first().text().replace('%', '').replace(' ', '');
                    }
                }
            },
            headers: { 0: { sorter: "digit" }
            }
        });
```

if radio button radio-choice-h-2a is checked, then sort by the content in the first span in each cell and if radio button radio-choice-h-2b is selected, then sort by the content in the second span element.

This doesn't seem to be working as intended. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textExtraction` function is only called when tablesorter is initialized or updated. So, if you have a cell with data you want to sort differently depending on some indicator, you'll need to use a combination of the `textExtraction` and `textSorter` functions. You can find two different methods in the answers of [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636761/how-to-sort-one-column-via-several-ways-in-a-header).

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3730/) of how it could be done

```html
Sort by: <label>Percent <input name="group" type="radio" checked="checked"/></label>
or
<label>Cost: <input name="group" type="radio"/></label>

<table id="test">
    <thead><tr><th>data</th><th>blah</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr><td><span>1.00 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$5,000</span></td><td>abc</td></tr>
     <tr><td><span>0.50 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$300.00</span></td><td>xyz</td></tr>
     <tr><td><span>1.40 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$0</span></td><td>def</td></tr>
     <tr><td><span>1.20 %</span>&nbsp;<span>$500</span></td><td>mno</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function () {

    var $sortby = $('input[name="group"]');

    $('#test').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            0: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
                var $n = $(node).find('span');
                // remove percent, commas and dollor signs
                // add semi-colon between values
                return $.trim( $n.eq(0).text().replace(/%/g,'') ) + ';' +
                    $.trim( $n.eq(1).text().replace(/[$,]/g,'') );
            }
        },
        textSorter: function (a, b) {
            // only use special sort if there is a semi-colon
            if (/;/.test(a)) {
                var x = a.split(';'),
                    y = b.split(';'),
                    i = $sortby.index( $sortby.filter(':checked') );
                return $.tablesorter.sortNatural(x[i], y[i]);
            } else {
                return $.tablesorter.sortNatural(a, b);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. The demo you provided is exactly what I needed. I was wondering if you know of any incompatibilities with Jquery mobile and table sorter. I am trying to use this in mobile along with Jquery mobile and it is not working as it does in your demo. It just sorts on the percentage values no matter what radio button is selected. Also, I couldn't find the funtion "textsorter" in my tablesorter.min.js file. When I replaced my tablesorter.min.js with the one attached in your demo, my table sorter stopped working altogether. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I've downloaded the latest version (2.17.7) from the URL http://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/ and it works just fine. The files I downloaded from http://www.tablesorter.com do not appear to be the latest ones. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Mottie, I am trying to trigger the sort when the radio button is clicked. I have this code to trigger an update. $('input:radio[name="group"]').change(
            function () {
                $('#test').trigger('update');
            }); But this code does not specify what column. Do you know how to trigger a sort on the column X when the radio button is clicked? Thanks.

Comment: The code I posted in the previous comment appears to be working but only when the header of the table is clicked at least once. After clicking the table header, when I click any radio button, the table is sorting properly. Is there a way to achieve this without first clicking the table header? Also, is there a way to always sort ascending when the radio button is clicked? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the [`sorton` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sorton) to force a sort; also, make sure that when you [trigger an update](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update), set the re-sort flag to `false`; here are the two combined: `$("table").trigger("update", [ false ]).trigger("sorton", [ [[0,0]] ]);`

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks Mottie. I was wondering how to sort rows within groups. Please find the fiddle I've created here (http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3820/). I am trying to achieve the sort functionality where the rows are sorted by the group column value. Rows with group value 1 should always be above the rows with group value 2 and they have to be sorted within each group. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the [`sortForce` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortforce).

Comment: The sortForce option appears to be for forcing sort on columns. I am trying to sort rows in groups.

Comment: Hi Mottie, I've solved my problem in kind of the same way as your first answer. I've updated the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3831/