# jquery tablesorter : determining sort order for column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible for http://tablesorter.com to sort on different values depending on whether the sort is ascending or descending ?

I see how to return sort values for a cell based on arbitrary data with a parser (i.e.: http://code-cocktail.in/hidden-value-sorting-in-jquery-tablesorter-plugin/ ) , so returning different values in different situations seems simple enough.

The bit I'm banging my head on is that I cannot seem to determine the sort order when parsing. It looks like I can re-parse cells when a sort is being requested via the following:

```
 $(".tablesorter").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        $(".tablesorter").trigger("update");
 });
```

... however it *looks* like at the "sortStart" point the order of the sort isn't known, so the parser cannot provide different values based on that column's sort order.

Is this possible ? Thanks :-)

Comment: can try poking through the data stored on main table element and see if there is any current sort settings there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following code to work, you'll need to use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which has css, widgets and addons that are not compatible with the original version.

---

This is somewhat similar to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636761/how-to-sort-one-column-via-several-ways-in-a-header) except that it allows sorting one column using two different values (both answers work nicely using different methods).

A minor modification is required to use one value during ascending sort and another during descending sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4971/)):

HTML (one cell)

```
<th class="gamename">
    <span class="name">Fun Fun</span>
    <span class="perc">96%</span>
</th>
```

Script

```
$(function () {

    $('#games').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            0: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
                var $n = $(node);
                // add semi-colon between values
                return $n.find('.name').text() + ';' + $n.find('.perc').text();
            }
        },
        textSorter: function (a, b, direction, columnIndex, table) {
            if (columnIndex === 0) {
                var c = table.config,
                    x = a.split(';'),
                    y = b.split(';'),
                    // sort column by percentage when descending sort is active
                    i = c.$headers.eq(0).hasClass('tablesorter-headerDesc') ? 1 : 0;
                return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
            } else {
                return $.tablesorter.sortNatural(a,b);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This really is stellar - thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction (thanks also for the demo - realy fantastic :-) ).

Comment: Great work @mottie  Thanks!   I used this to learn about textSorter in general, but then to simply always add another sort column first, whenever sort is run....