# Custom sort buttons in jquery tablesorter headers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

so my table contains 3 kinds of data per cell.. i'd like to ask if it's possible to add 3 sort buttons per header cell that sets the data in the cell that will be sorted, and at the same time, sort the rows?

a header cell contains something like this:

```
[Header Title] 
- - - - - - - - - -
[sort by A] [sort by B] [sort by C]
```

and a data cell contains something like this:

```
[data A] | [data B] | [data C]
```

when i click on `[sort by B]` button, the cells should be sorted by their `[data B]` values

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this type of requirement right for the first time and out of curiosity, I tried a [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/z6qqby9p/) of it (only the structure but not the functionality).

I see it as every possibility that it can be done with ease, and on the basis of the click of the either of the *sort by* items, the respective data can be sorted using any sorting algorithm, written in the JavaScript, just one needs to call the respective method in the JS.

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1
        <div>
          <a class="control-label" href="#" onclick="sortBy1()">Sort by 1</a>
          <a class="control-label" href="#" onclick="sortBy2()">Sort by 2</a>
          <a class="control-label" href="#" onclick="sortBy3()">Sort by 3</a>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Text 11</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 12</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 13</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">ABC 11</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Pqr 11</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Text 21</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 22</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 23</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">ABC 21</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Pqr 21</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Text 31</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 32</span>
        <span class="control-label">Text 33</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">ABC 31</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="control-label">Pqr 31</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
function sortBy1(){}
function sortBy2(){}
function sortBy3(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), there is already a question/answer here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24636761/145346) relating to sorting two sets of data in a cell. I slightly modified the code to allow for 3+ data sets per cell. Here is [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/7862/):

```
$(function() {

  var $cell;
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textSorter: function(a, b) {
      var x = a.split('|'),
        y = b.split('|'),
        i = $cell.filter('.active').attr('data-index');
      return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
    },
    initialized: function() {
      $cell = $('table thead th').find('span');
      $cell.click(function() {
        // activate percentage sort
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
        return false;
      });

    }
  });

});
```